# How to make a favourite list iphone

Tags: iphone, core-data, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I am making an app that has two tabs, one of which is a "favourite" tab. In the other tab called "search", I have a list of results displayed in a table view, when you tap one, you get to see the detail of that particular result. What I'm trying to do here is, there is a button in the detail view, when it is pressed, the current result gets sent to the "favourite" tab. I tried to use delegate to pass the information, but it didn't work out. Here is my code:

DetailViewController.m

```
-(IBAction) addSomething {  
    [self.delegate detailViewController:self addToFavourite:self.something];
}
```

FavouriteViewController.m, implement the delegate method:

```
- (void) detailViewController:(DetailViewController *)detailViewController addToFavourite:(Something *)something{
    detailViewController.delegate = self;
    [thingsList addObject:something];
    [theTableView reloadData];
}
```

Everything is built and fine, but when I click "add" button in the detail view, the data doesn't get sent to "favourite" tab's view. Can anyone help me with this one? Do I need to use core data in this case, I never used core data before. Thanks.

Comment: Will this data persist beyond the app life cycle? Or will it be reloaded each time the app is used?

Comment: The favourite list should be persistent, so I wonder if I should use core data...

Comment: Up to you. For something small like an array, user defaults works great. Much less overhead than dealing with CoreData. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it that is drop dead easy is storing your information in NSUserDefaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
[defaults setObject:thingsList forKey:@"myData"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

When you load your data up in your other tab, just fill it from user defaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
otherData = [defaults objectForKey:@"myData"];
```

I probably abuse user defaults more than I should, but it makes for a very easy way to store your data locally and have it persist between runs. It will also backup with iTunes for added persistence. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, there is one question, where do I init the "thingList"?

Comment: thinkList can be whatever you want it to be. NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, whatever you need it to be. Just init it wherever you need it and add it as an object to your NSUserDefaults.

Comment: But every time I init it, and set the object for the same key, the original data would be overridden, right? How can I persist the thingsList every time a detail view is loaded?

Comment: I see. You could just have 2 different ivars. I just reused the same one for the example. Pull the data in as thingList1 and store as thingsList2. I have a similar situation in my app. I use a for loop to update all of my new incoming data and merge it with the existing data, then store the new updated data. It can be very flexible, but you will have to decide how you want to use it.

Comment: So where do I init thingList2 which stores the existing data?